# How to get a method/property description? [C#]

Tags: c#, field-description

How can I get the description of this property for example: (?)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// **This indicates whether the ToolTip is Activated.**
    /// </summary>
    private bool _visible
    {
        get { return rtbScript.ToolTip.Active; }
        set { rtbScript.ToolTip.Active = value; }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with description?

Comment: Xml doc would be tricky. [Description] would be easier

Comment: The string located inside the <summary> </summary>..

Comment: What do you want to use it for? Do you want to generate documentation from your source code or do you want to use it at runtime (for example, to display it to a user)?

Comment: I want to display the comments to the user.. but due to @EZI's comment I now suspect that it is not possible.. :/

Comment: It is possible to do. However you'll need to write a MEF Extension for VS or a VSPackage. This allows you to get the info at **edit time** by either parsing the file or querying the **classifiers**. Those other answers don't mention this and they seem to be focused on runtime